# Gnome shell - Remove bottom panel

Tags: gnome

I have tried many solutions, but bottom bar is still there.

[image]

Tried with Tweak Tool but there's no option *Remove bottom bar extension* in this version.
Any help?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove bottom panel follow the below steps from [Wey on the Arch Linux forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=120063):

> - Edit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css: Search for
>     #message-tray and comment the block out with /* ... */. This will remove the black bar, but not the icons and their text.
> - Next go to /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/messageTray.js: Search for ICON_SIZE (its in line 881 here) and set it to 0:
>
>   ```
>   ICON_SIZE: 0,
>   ```
>
>   About three lines below it states
>
>   ```
>   this.title = title;
>   ```
>
>   Make it
>
>   ```
>   this.title = '';
>   ```
>
>   This makes the whole thing disappear.

**(OR)** use yanir's solution from the same thread:

> - Edit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css: Search for
>     #message-tray and comment the block out with /* ... */. This will remove the black bar, but not the icons and their text.
> - edit   /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/messageTray.js the following way:
>     (the last class at the end of the file)
>
>   ```
>   const SystemNotificationSource = new Lang.Class({
>       Name: 'SystemNotificationSource',
>       Extends: Source,
>       _init: function() {
>           this.parent(_("System Information"));
>           this._setSummaryIcon(this.createNotificationIcon());
>       },
>       createNotificationIcon: function() {
>   //        return new St.Icon({ icon_name: 'dialog-information',
>   //                             icon_type: St.IconType.SYMBOLIC,
>   //                             icon_size: this.ICON_SIZE });
>           return 0;
>       },
>       open: function() {
>           this.destroy();
>       }
>   });
>   ```

Answer (score 3):

A fantastically neat way to do this, via a Gnome Shell extension and no code hacking, is to install **Dash to Dock**:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

You don't have to have its dock enabled.

In the main tab, set:

- `Dock is fixed and always visible` to `OFF` and
- `Autohide and Intellihide` to `OFF`

In the optional tab, set:

- `Make message tray insensitive to mouse events` to `ON`.

Voila!

Comment: This seems to be a complete replacement for the Gnome extension "Insensitive message tray". Superb! [@Marco](http://askubuntu.com/users/231100/marko-koji%c4%87) could you mark this as answer.